# how to set up cron job for laravel Task scheduler in media temple DV hosting

Tags: laravel, cron, mediatemple

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8ImJ.jpg)I am having problem in setting the cron job for laravel Task scheduler in MediaTemple DV hosting server. I have attached the error message. I will be grateful is somebody show me the guideline. Thankyou.

Comment: You did not attach the error message.

Comment: Sorry my mistake now i have given the image description. Error is "-": 1 bad command errors in crontab file, can't install. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Instead of  *****php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1              I removed ***** from the begining to php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1. It solved the problem, hope someone find useful.